# Enforce release dependencies except on modules from the same build

Tags: java, maven

I have a Maven aggregator project X, consisting of modules A and B. In the first stage of my delivery pipeline I want to build the current snapshot version of X, but enforce that all dependencies are releases. (The purpose is to ensure that the project is in releasable state, where releases must not have snapshot dependencies.)

A and B refer to X as their parent, and (to complicate matters) B has A as a dependency. (I configured the Maven Enforcer Plugin to apply the Reactor Module Convergence rule.)

Is it possible to persuade the maven-enforcer-plugin to enforce release versions of all dependencies, except to projects in the current reactor build?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an import/export mechanism built into the [`requireReleaseDeps`](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/requireReleaseDeps.html) rule of the [Maven Enforcer Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/index.html). For example, if you want to require that all dependencies are using release versions, except those located in the group id `my-group-id`, you would have:

```
<requireReleaseDeps>
  <message>No Snapshots Allowed!</message>
  <excludes>
    <exclude>my-group-id:*</exclude>
  </excludes>
</requireReleaseDeps>
```

The String passed to the includes or excludes are documented in the [`AbstractStrictPatternArtifactFilter`](https://maven.apache.org/shared-archives/maven-common-artifact-filters-1.4/apidocs/org/apache/maven/shared/artifact/filter/AbstractStrictPatternArtifactFilter.html) class: they follow the format `[groupId]:[artifactId]:[type]:[version]`, where each part can also contain wildcard `*`.

This works fine if all the project in your reactor share the same group id. You can also add more `<exclude>` elements to specifically target each of those projects by specifying each of their artifact ids. [MENFORCER-185](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MENFORCER-185) is an enhancement request to add a `allowSnapshotsInReactor` boolean and handle projects from the reactor differently than with include/exclude, which would provide a cleaner solution, but it is not resolved as of today.

Comment: Eagerly awaiting for MENFORCER-185 to be shipped in the next version of the plug-in!

Answer (score 2):

The [scijava-maven-plugin](https://github.com/scijava/scijava-maven-plugin) provides an enforcer rule called [`requireReproducibleBuilds`](https://github.com/scijava/scijava-maven-plugin/blob/scijava-maven-plugin-1.0.0/src/main/java/org/scijava/maven/plugin/enforcer/RequireReproducibleBuilds.java#L53-L69) which enforces that all dependencies outside the reactor are releases, while allowing snapshots between reactor modules.

Add the following to the `maven-enforcer-plugin`'s `<dependencies>` section:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.scijava</groupId>
    <artifactId>scijava-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

And the following to the `maven-enforcer-plugin` configuration's `<rules>` section:

```xml
<!--
Require builds to be reproducible.
This means no snapshot dependencies!
-->
<requireReproducibleBuilds implementation="org.scijava.maven.plugin.enforcer.RequireReproducibleBuilds">
    <groupIds>org.foo,org.bar</groupIds>
</requireReproducibleBuilds>
```

Where `org.foo` and `org.bar` are the groupIds for components you want to ensure have reproducible dependency structures.

See [here](https://github.com/scijava/pom-scijava-base/blob/pom-scijava-base-3.2.0/pom.xml) for an example configuration.

Comment: Thanks for this alternative